# Make div with background image on line with span in paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im currently trying to implement a debug console in my application. For this i have a main div with the following CSS:

```
#~main_div~ {
    display: none; /* gets set to display: block when the users wants the console */
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 25%;
    max-height: 350px;
    background-color: rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.8);
    text-align: left;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

The id ~main_div~ is replaced by the element thats actually holding the debug console for a loaded frame (all of this correctly shows)

Then i add messages to that div which in general are of the following format:

```
<p>
    <span class="title_notice">[timestamp] Title: </span>
    <span class="message_notice">The message</span>
</p>
```

Yet sometimes i want to display images inlined in the text (like The [an image] message). I have done this the following way (example):

```
<p>
     <span class="title_notice">[timestamp] Title: </span>
     <span class="message_notice">The 
         <div style="display: inline-block; width: 25px; height: 25px; background-image:url(...);"></div>
         message
     </span>
</p>
```

If you wonder why im using a div and not an img: Its possible to give an offset inside the image and a size so that it displays only a portion of the image, and afaik you cant do that with `img`.

The result sadly looks like this:
http://puu.sh/6gwdH.jpg (sorry, i cannot attach the image because of rep...)

Problem 1: The div is on a new linew
Problem 2: The format on the span (which is actually set by `#~main_div~ p` (font family, font size and font weight) and .message_notice (color)) is lost

Is there a way to 'inline' an image in a text so that its on the same line and the format does not break and im able to select only a portion of the image? **Oh, and the solution only has to work for webkit, no portability is required.**

Many thanks in advance and greetings
Cromon

Comment: Have you tried adding display:inline-block ?

Comment: You're putting a block element (`div`) inside of an inline element (the `span`) = not good.

Comment: Oh, ive forgotten to add a tiny detail:
if i add `display: inline` to the paragraph and add an empty <div></div> at the end of every paragraph it sort of works. Problem 2 remains, the remainder of the span does not have the format the start of the span has, see: http://puu.sh/6gxlu.jpg

Comment: like this.. http://jsfiddle.net/7DbxG/ ?

Comment: Is it possble with an `img` tag do display only a portion of an image? like from 10/10 to 50/50? Like what i would do with background-position.

Comment: Not as easy, there's the background image way.. http://jsfiddle.net/7DbxG/1/. Hope this is what you were after!

Comment: you gave me the right way to go! Right now im doing it like this. Considering i want to display the image image_url and the portion from x/y with the width w/h, so it would become: `<span style="background-position: -xpx -ypx; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain; padding-left: wpx; background-image: url(image_url);"></span>` which becomes: http://puu.sh/6gyTX.jpg